# Deploy Appfuse in with Jboss EAP 6.1

Tags: hibernate, jboss, appfuse

I use Appfuse with struts2 and trying to deploy in Jboss EAP 6.1. Thing I have tried:
Add: jboss-deployment-structure.xml in WEB-INF/:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.hibernate" />
    </exclusions>
</deployment>
```

And add property in Persistant.xml:

```
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
    <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="application" />
</properties>
```

After that, I get error about ClassCastException:

```
05:13:07,640 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."claim.war#ApplicationEntityManager": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."claim.war#ApplicationEntityManager": java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator could not be instantiated: java.lang.ClassCastException
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look at JBoss Developer QuickStart sample projects. For example:

https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts/tree/master/hibernate3

Comment: But I'm looking for a solution that can make me quickly deploy in both tomcat, jetty (when dev/debug) and Jboss EAP, so I try to exclude the Jboss lib and use only lib in WAR.